# HTML make element invalid drop target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application in which a user can drop stuff from one list to another list. Each list has a number of `div`s as elements each with their own children. I'm relying on the id of the parent div to detect where the drop was performed but sometimes the children consume the events since the cursor was above them at the time. Is there any way to avoid that by adding something like `droptarget="false"` to those children?

I don't think the code in necessary (and its too much) but anyway:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}css/assembler.css">

<div class="width_match_parent box_sizing_border flex_container_row flex_align_item_start  material_blue_500 padding_large">
    <div id="template_assembler_div_card_list" class="layout_weight_2 box_sizing_border flex_container_column padding_large">
        <!-- ======================================================================================== -->
        <div id="card_1" draggable="true" class="assembler_workflow_card card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text" ondragover="return true">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======================================================================================== -->
        <div id="card_2" draggable="true" class="assembler_workflow_card card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======================================================================================== -->
        <div id="card_3" draggable="true" class="assembler_workflow_card card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======================================================================================== -->
        <div id="card_4" draggable="true" class="assembler_workflow_card card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======================================================================================== -->
        <div id="card_5" draggable="true" class="assembler_workflow_card card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ======================================================================================== -->
    </div>
    <div class="layout_weight_1 box_sizing_border flex_container_column flex_justify_content_start padding_large">
        <ul class="collection">
            <li draggable="true" class="collection-item ">Alvin</li>
            <li draggable="true" class="collection-item ">Alvin</li>
            <li draggable="true" class="collection-item ">Alvin</li>
            <li draggable="true" class="collection-item ">Alvin</li>
        </ul>
        <p draggable="true">This is a draggable paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
ANIMATION_DIRECTION_UP = -1 ;
ANIMATION_DIRECTION_DOWN = 1 ;

// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //

var initialized = false ;
var dragging = false ;
var animating = false ;

// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //

var workflow_cards_div ;
workflow_cards = [] ;
var dragged_workflow_card ;
var current_drag_target ;
var current_animation_direction ;

function WorkflowCard(element) {
    this.element = element ;
    this.width = element.outerWidth ;
    this.height = element.outerHeight ;
}

WorkflowCard.prototype = {

}

function get_workflow_card(id) {
    // console.log(workflow_cards.length) ;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < workflow_cards.length ; i++) {
        // console.log(i + ':' + workflow_cards[i].element)
        if (workflow_cards[i].element.id == id) {
            return workflow_cards[i] ;
        }
    }
}

function get_animation_targets(workflow_card) {
    if (current_animation_direction == ANIMATION_DIRECTION_UP) {
        return get_animation_workflow_cards(workflow_card, true) ;
    } else {
        return get_animation_workflow_cards(workflow_card, false) ;
    }
}

function get_animation_workflow_cards(workflow_card, d) {
    l = [] ;
    var add = d ;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < workflow_cards.length ; i++) {
        if (workflow_cards[i].element.id == workflow_card.element.id) {
            add = !d ;
        }
        if (add) {
            l.push(workflow_cards[i]) ;
        }
    }
    return l ;
}

// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //

function initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = true ;
        get_all_workflow_cards() ;
    }
}

function get_all_workflow_cards() {
    $('div.assembler_workflow_card').each(function(index, element) {
        console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(element)) ;
        workflow_cards.push(new WorkflowCard(element)) ;
    }) ;
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call($('#card_1')))
    console.log($('#card_1')) ;
}

function initialize_dimensions() {
    workflow_card_div = document.getElementById('template_assembler_div_card_list') ;
}

// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //

document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {
    initialize() ;
    if (!dragging) {
        if (get_workflow_card(event.target.id)) {
            dragged_workflow_card = get_workflow_card(event.target.id) ;
            console.log('being dragged:' + dragged_workflow_card.element.id) ;
            dragging = true ;
        }
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault() ;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
    console.log('entering: ' + event.target.id)
    target = get_workflow_card(event.target.id) ;
    if (target == undefined) {

    }
    if (target.element.id != dragged_workflow_card.element.id) {
        if (!animating) {
            animating = true ;
            console.log('dragenter ' + target.element.id) ;
            position = $('#' + target.element.id).position() ;
            center = {
                x: position.left + target.width / 2,
                y: position.top + target.height / 2
            }
            drag_position = {
                x: event.screenX,
                y: event.screenY
            }
            if (drag_position.y < center.y) {
                // from above, move them down
                console.log('from above, move them down') ;
                current_animation_direction = ANIMATION_DIRECTION_DOWN ;
            } else {
                // from below, move them up
                console.log('from below, move them up') ;
                current_animation_direction = ANIMATION_DIRECTION_UP ;
            }
            animation_targets = get_animation_targets(target) ;
            // console.log(animation_targets) ;
            for (var i = 0 ; i < animation_targets.length ; i++) {
                console.log(animation_targets[i]) ;
                console.log('animating ' + animation_targets[i].element.id)
                $('#' + animation_targets[i].element.id).animate({
                    "top": "+=100"
                }) ;
                // document.getElementById(animation_targets[i].element.id).animate([
                //  {transform: 'translateY(' + current_animation_direction * dragged_workflow_card.height + 'px)'}
                // ],
                // {
                //  duration: 500,
                //  iterations: 1,
                //  easing: "ease-in-out",
                // }) ;
            }
        }
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragleave", function( event ) {
    if (!event.target) {
        return ;
    }
    target = get_workflow_card(event.target.id) ;
    if (target != undefined) {
        // center = target
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault() ;
    dragging = false ;
}, false);

// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //
// ============================================================================================== //

$(document).ready(function() {
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'd think you'd want the logic to be in the `drop` event listener, but you seem to have it in the `dragenter` event listener. Regardless, you can detect if an event is triggered on the parent element or the child element by comparing the event `target` vs `currentTarget` properties. The `currentTarget` is always the element that had the event listener defined on it.

In your case, instead of adding the drag event listeners to the document, you might want to add them to the parent elements that you are concerned about. Then you can determine the id of the parent element by looking at the event.currentTarget, or by storing the id in the event listener callback.